# Video window not fitting to width of screen

Tags: jquery, css, html, video, flash

I have this website here: www.bigideaadv.com/xsp and I'm trying to get a video to pop up when you click on the watch video link. The issue is that I want it to expand the width of the browser and the height of the browser - 242px. It works fine in Firefox, it resizes the video when you resize the window. In Safari and IE 7+, no dice. The variables are updating with new values on resize, but it won't update the css properties. It stays at the inital value of the video. Anyone have any thoughts? Thanks in advance. Code to follow:

```
function resize() {
    var viewportwidth;
    var viewportheight;

    // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) 
    // use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined') {
        viewportwidth = window.innerWidth, viewportheight = window.innerHeight
        //alert(viewportwidth);
        //alert(viewportheight);
    }

    // IE6 in standards compliant mode 
    //(i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)
    else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined' 
          && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth != 'undefined' 
          && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) {
        viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
        viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
    }

    // older versions of IE
    else {
        viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
        viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
    }

    viewportheight = viewportheight - 242;

    $('#sublime_video_wrapper_0').css('width', viewportwidth);
    $('#sublime_video_wrapper_0').css('height', viewportheight);
    $('#sublime_vixdeo_wrapper_0').css('z-index', '1003');
    $('#slide1video embed').css('width', viewportwidth);
    $('#slide1video embed').css('height', viewportheight);
    $('#slide1video embed').css('z-index', '1002');
    $('#slide1video').css('width', viewportwidth);
    $('#slide1video').css('height', viewportheight);
    $('#slide1video').css('z-index', '1001');
    $('video.sublime').css('width', viewportwidth);
    $('video.sublime').css('height', viewportheight);
    $('video.sublime').css('z-index', '1000');
};​
```

Comment: Did you try $(window).width() and $(window).height() to get the dimension of browser viewport?

Answer (score 0):

instead of all this javascript...you can achieve this using just css.... just specify the width and height of the video as 100% and its parent css property as `max-width:100%;`

Comment: That won't work because I don't want it to fill the screen completely. I want the header and footer to remain visible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your CSS, i'm not sure how sublime video works but the video container appear to have a fixed height of 200px & a fixed width of 400px. I would give this a try:

```
#sublime_video_wrapper_0{
   width:100% !important;
   height:100% !important;
}
```

That should fix the issue for webkit browsers, maybe even IE but I haven't tested it.

Comment: I've tried that too. It just makes the video window 200px x 200px.

Comment: Does you container(#slide1video) have a fixed height & width?

Comment: Well I haven't set one, but the hosted javascript may inherit the width and height of the video itself. The Sublime Video JS is meant to handle full screen video. I just need it to change size when you resize the browser.